# Converting String's to enums with custom names in Groovy

Tags: groovy, enums, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `String` into an enum in Groovy, but I want to use a different name from the literal enum name.

Let's say I have some enum which uses a custom name like so:

```
enum Breed {
    HUSKY('Husky'),
    LABRADOR('Labrador'),
    POODLE('Poodle')

    private final String name

    Breed(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    String toString() {
        name
    }
}
```

As it currently stands, I could get a `Breed` with the following code:

```
Breed breed = 'HUSKY' as Breed
```

However, I would like to be able to override this behavior to use the name field instead like so:

```
Breed breed = 'Husky' as Breed
```

Is there a method I can implement or override in this enum to first check the name field? Ideally, I would like to avoid having to override the `asType` method in `String` to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: The `asType` route would be the most obvious.  Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Also, using the class name `Number` is probably going to cause you pain in the future

Comment: @cfrick It just requires additional initialization which is a hassle I'd simply like to avoid if possible. Since I know Groovy handles a specific case where a String is being coerced into an enum, I wanted to see if I could intercept that behavior instead of overhauling it entirely.

Comment: @tim_yates No worries, this was just an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for an internal lookup:

- provide a Look-Up-Table
- add a helper to get an element by key

E.g.

```
enum Breed {
    HUSKY('Husky'),
    LABRADOR('Labrador'),
    POODLE('Poodle')

    private final String name

    Breed(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    public static final LUT = Breed.values().collectEntries{ [it.name, it] }.asImmutable()

    static from(String name) { 
        assert LUT.containsKey(name)
        LUT.get(name) 
    }
}

assert Breed.from("Husky") == Breed.HUSKY
```

Comment: The answer here is certainly a concise way, but I'm curious if there's any real benefit to doing this instead of `Breed.find{it.name =="Husky"}​​​​`

Comment: Linear search vs a map lookup comes to mind (which is basically nothing for your three items example).  The bigger improvement IMHO is the fact, that you give your operation a proper name (you can refactor it easily, it speaks for itself, ...) and you can steer a global "error handling" inside the `from` function - "want to use an `Optional`?" - go for it!